# MySQL: Big Database - request 0,10 Limit... resources?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to know, what's the best way **to get the last 10 new entries** from a database (MySQL)? Sure, at the moment I'm using:

*(SELECT whatever FROM whatever ORDER BY id (or whatever) DESC **LIMIT 0,10**)*

But what happens, if you have hundreds of entries or thousands? Does MySQL still select and just "read" only the last ten entries - and doesn't lost speed & time crawling through all other entries?

For my purpose I'll always just need the last 10~20 entries from the database, the rest & old ones are more for archive-stuff. Every entry/record has an auto-increment-ID, which I use to show via ORDER and SELECT my entries (using PHP ~ PDO and prepared statments) and I love minimal and solutions, that don't require a lot of resources.

Good enough or are there better ways?
Thanks for your thoughts and explanations! :)

Comment: create index on column u want use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution will always work fast no matter the size of the database, provided you have an index on the relevant columns (in this case `id`, which I assume is a primary key).

The reason is that the indexes are stored as B-Trees with low height and therefore are extremly fast to search in. I recommend this website for you as a background reading: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy/the-tree

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply - good to hear & I'll take a closer look into "the tree"... :)